# Is there a way to automatically set the theme of a Gtk3 GUI according to system theme in Python?

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, vala

I'm making a GUI for an Elementary OS app in Python, using Gtk3 for the GUI. I want to set the theme (light/dark/whichever theme is being used in Gnome) automatically according to the theme on the system. The documentation for Vala and demo program for Granite describes a way to do this:

```
var gtk_settings = Gtk.Settings.get_default ();
var granite_settings = Granite.Settings.get_default ();

gtk_settings.gtk_application_prefer_dark_theme = granite_settings.prefers_color_scheme == Granite.Settings.ColorScheme.DARK;
```

However, I can't seem to find any documentation in doing this in Python Gtk3+ (using `from gi.repository import Gtk`).
Am I just missing something?

Comment: OS, as in MacOS? The theme for Gtk apps is set automatically in Linux (or at least Ubuntu, which is GNOME).

Comment: @SylvesterKruin I meant "elementary OS", it's an Ubuntu distribution. Sorry for not capitalizing the 'e', now I realize it may lead to confusion. Thanks for the answer! It explains a lot, Elementary uses Gnome as well